# How to get historical data for stocks in BSE or NSE exchanges in India?

Tags: india, historical-data, online-data-source, nse-india, bse-india

For research purposes, I need historical data for the last two years or so of companies listed in the [National Stock Exchange of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Stock_Exchange_of_India) (NSE) or [Bombay Stock Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombay_Stock_Exchange) (BSE). I looked around in the forums and couldn't come across anything that suited me.

It seems Google Finance and Yahoo Finance do not offer this data anymore. If anyone has any info on this, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/NSE-National-Stock-Exchange-of-India)? They have historical data for NSE listed equities.

Comment: I have heard about them. But I am not looking for a premium service at the moment.

Comment: @vipin : Then, AlphaVantage may be something for you. To access data, request an API key and then make an API call: (https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NSE:INFY&outputsize=full&apikey=<YOUR-API-HERE>)

Comment: I did. But it doesnt work for me. Did it work for you in the past?

Comment: Yes. It worked for me.